# How can i run the multiple JMX file in one container?

Tags: docker, automation, jmeter, containers

I am using JMeter for testing API and Docker. I want to run JMX files in one container. Currently, i can run one JMX files in one container.

And this script that's I used for running my tests is :

`docker-compose exec master jmeter -p /jmeter/sample/stage.properties -n -t /jmeter/sample/mob.jmx.`

How can i run the multiple JMX file in one container? Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using i.e. [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) command like:

```
docker-compose exec master parallel jmeter -p /jmeter/sample/stage.properties -n -t /jmeter/sample/mob{}.jmx -l /jmeter/sample/mob{}.jtl ::: 1 2
```

this way `mob1.jmx` and `mob2.jmx` will be executed at the same time and results will be written into `mob1.jtl` and `mob2.jtl` files correspondingly.

Another option is using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for JMeter tests, you can declare your tests  in a simple [YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) file like:

```
---
execution:
- scenario:
    script: /jmeter/sample/mob1.jmx
- scenario: 
    script: /jmeter/sample/mob2.jmx
```

and [Taurus will start them in parallel](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests/).

---

You might need to install GNU parallel or Taurus to your container first, most probably none of them is installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

replace your call to the single jmx file with a bash script, that then calls the multiple jmeter scripts